# Фото галереи на jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Дальше справа есть еще изображения и миниатюры... Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на миниатюру они все смещались влево?

[image]

Вот скрипт галереи:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var total = $("#img_box img").length;

    $("#imglink1 img").css({
        "border-color": "#2872a6",
        "top": "-5px"
    });

    $(".thumblink").click(function () {
        var imgnumber = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace("imglink", ""));
        var move = -($("#img" + imgnumber).width() * (imgnumber - 1));

        $("#img_box").animate({
            left: move
        }, 500);

        $("#imgthumb_box").find("img").removeAttr("style");
        $(this).find("img").css({
            "border-color": "#2872a6",
            "top": "-5px",
            "border-top-width": "-5px"
        });
        return false;
    });

    $("#navigate a").click(function () {
        var imgwidth = $("#img1").width();
        var box_left = $("#img_box").css("left");
        var el_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var move, imgnumber;

        if (box_left == 'auto') {
            box_left = 0;
        } else {
            box_left = parseInt(box_left.replace("px", ""));
        }

        // Если нажата кнопка для перехода на предыдущее изображение
        if (el_id == 'linkprev') {
            if ((box_left - imgwidth) == -(imgwidth)) {
                move = -(imgwidth * (total - 1));
            } else {
                move = box_left + imgwidth;
            }

            imgnumber = -(box_left / imgwidth);
            if (imgnumber == 0) {
                imgnumber = total;
            }
        } else if (el_id == 'linknext') {
            // Если изображение последнее, то переходим на первую картинку
            if (-(box_left) == (imgwidth * (total - 1))) {
                move = 0;
            } else {
                move = box_left - imgwidth;
            }

            imgnumber = Math.abs((box_left / imgwidth)) + 2;
            if (imgnumber == (total + 1)) {
                imgnumber = 1;
            }
        } else if (el_id == 'linkfirst') {
            move = 0;
            imgnumber = 1;
        } else if (el_id == 'linklast') {
            move = -(imgwidth * (total - 1));
            imgnumber = total;
        }

        // Стили для выбранной картинки
        $("#imgthumb_box").find("img").removeAttr("style");
        $("#imglink" + imgnumber).find("img").css({
            "border-color": "#2872a6",
            "top": "-5px",
            "border-top-width": "-5px"
        });

        $("#navigate a").hide();
        $("#navigate span").show();

        $("#img_box").animate({
            left: move + 'px'
        }, 400, function () {
            $("#navigate a").show();
            $("#navigate span").hide();
        });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Так понимаю, галерею эту писали не вы, возьмите просто аналогичную, полностью работающую под ваши нужды. Вот [набор галерей](http://blueprintds.com/2009/01/20/top-14-jquery-photo-slideshow-gallery-plugins/).